# Windows Server 2012 - How to FTP over VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I have setup & am connected from Windows 8 to Windows Server 2012 using a VPN.

I have an FTP server setup on the server on port 21. This is blocked by an external hardware firewall. I can connect to this from the server itself (so shows FTP is working).

Once I am connected to the VPN, how can I then connect to the FTP server?

I think I need a 'local' IP address - but I can't see one when I run ipconfig on the Server?

It doesn't work using the external IP to the server (the one I use to connect to the VPN).

I can't find even 1 article on Google about this at all (spent hours looking).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your FTP server is successfully connected to its LAN, it has a local ip address and that shows under `ipconfig`.
Alternatively, type `netstat -an` and look for lines with "LISTEN" and port 21.

Comment: Thanks. Nothing under ipconfig that's not external IP. in netstat, only things on port 21: 0.0.0.0:21 & [::]:21 & an IPv6:21

Comment: Hm, do you imply that the hw firewall actually exposes the original ip of the box? Is the VPN really established *with* the firewall or *through* the firewall to the windows box? In the latter case another (tunnel) interface should be active during VPN sessions, typically with an RFC1918 address and you should be able to FTP to that. In the former case I don't see how the routing is handled in that setup

Comment: Funny thing - I can use an IPv6 address (link local) - that works when connected to the VPN (and not when disconnected). But I can see no IPv4 to use?!